# uppercase function not working in php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have a PHP file in which I want to convert the user input into uppercase letter , so I used strtoupper() function of PHP but it is not working.Here is my code

```
$eno =@$_SESSION['eno'];
$eno =strtoupper($eno);
```

Now on inserting this into database , it is still in lowercase letters.Here is the insert query.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `student_info`(`student_no`,`High_School_Name`, `Year_Of_Passing`, `Higher_Secondary_School_Name`, `Year_Of_Passing1`, `Enrollment_Number`, `Roll_Number`, `Current_Course`, `Current_Sem`, `Current_section`, `Enrollment_Year`, `Alternate_Email`)VALUES('$studentno','$High_School_Name','$Year_Of_Passing10','$Higher_Secondary_School_Name','$Year_Of_Passing12','$eno','$Roll_Number','$Current_Course','$Current_Sem','$Current_section','$Enrollment_Year','$Alternate_Email' )";
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to insert `$eno` into the database?

Comment: strtoupper works just fine, the problem is elsewhere

Comment: Try this, right after you make the string uppercase, do: var_dump($eno); exit; and look at the output. Also could you post the entire code? The query doesn't help us.

Comment: Also your sql query is unsecure, you need to escape your variables, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Actually I have created the sessions so the code is transferred from one page to other. So i am unable to show you the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $eno='vikram';
 echo $eno =strtoupper($eno);
```

[image]

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO `student_info`(`student_no`,`High_School_Name`, `Year_Of_Passing`, `Higher_Secondary_School_Name`, `Year_Of_Passing1`, `Enrollment_Number`, `Roll_Number`, `Current_Course`, `Current_Sem`, `Current_section`, `Enrollment_Year`, `Alternate_Email`)VALUES('".$studentno."','".$High_School_Name."','".$Year_Of_Passing10."','".$Higher_Secondary_School_Name."','".$Year_Of_Passing12."',ucase('".$eno."'),'".$Roll_Number."','".$Current_Course."','".$Current_Sem."','".$Current_section."','".$Enrollment_Year."','".$Alternate_Email."' )";
```

use this function in query: select UCASE ('vikram')

[image]

Comment: Rajat doing the same thing. :)
Problem is anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem

```
echo $eno;
```

.. and look at the results.

Comment: Yes i do this and it successfully converts the letter into uppercase

Comment: Then the problem has nothing to do with `strupper`.